# Simple Web Application Pinging in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Are there any features in Jenkins that allow me to simply send an email to users if a website is down?  I'm not looking for anything complicated, just a simple notification that a 404 type error is being thrown when a request to the website/ web service/ etc is sent.  I already have email notification working for build fails for my projects in Jenkins, so email notification is not the issue... I just want to see if there exists anything in Jenkins that detects if a site is down without having to write a unit test.

Yes, I'm lazy.

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking for a monitoring tool?

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm not interested in network traffic or anything like that... it's an internal development server.  Does Jenkins come with a built-in automated ping to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SiteMonitor+Plugin ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I want, thanks.  There are other variations, such as https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin .  Much appreciated.

Comment: @reto put comment in as an answer and I can upvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various Jenkins plugins that provide this functionality, some of them are:

- http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SiteMonitor+Plugin
- http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin